# How to get specific parts of a page using cheerio

Tags: node.js, discord.js, cheerio, steam

So, i'm trying to make a discordbot to check every x time if a game is on sale on someone's wishlist. But i can't get to make cheerio read some of the properties of the page. If i log ".wishlist_row" for example it will be and empty log. Also when i tried to log the whole page text, it wouldn't log the name of the games and the prices... How do I scrape this data?

I've tried this :

```
console.log("Starting to log Steam wishlists updates!")
    setInterval(function () {
        request("https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/id/myusername/#sort=order", async (error, response, html) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        console.log($('.wishlist_row').text())
            $('.wishlist_row').each((i, element) => {
                console.log($(element).find('.discount_pct'))
            })
        }
    })
}, 1000)
```

Comment: what is the value of the `html` parameter? are you sure it is a HTML string? console.log it out and see

Comment: i did, i logged html.text() and it only showed up stuff like selecting languages, the account's name etc. But nothing about the wishlist stuff...

Comment: Are you programmatically logging in to the respective account before using cheerio on the HTML string? I might be that you are using cheerio on a page that is just not logged in to an account

Comment: i'm getting hte link without logging in, i have my own wishlist open to everyone so it doesn't require a login to access it.

Comment: As a test of the CSS selector, are you able to select from the same DOM, using jQuery and getting your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Cheerio can read from the source code of a web page, but it can't render JavaScript to create the full experience you see on a browser.

The wishlist item element you see when you view a person's wishlist in the browser is fetched from elsewhere and rendered using JavaScript, so you won't be able to get this sort of information from scraping the page's source code.

However, Steam does offer a public API that you can call to get this data at
`https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/id/{myusername}/wishlistdata/?p=0`

Using this API, you can access each game's current discount percentage like so:

```
console.log("Starting to log Steam wishlists updates!")
    setInterval(function () {
        request("https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/id/{myusername}/wishlistdata/?p=0", (error, response) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                let wishlist = JSON.parse(response.body);

                for (let appid in wishlist) {
                    console.log(wishlist[appid]); // game information
                    console.log(wishlist[appid].subs[0].discount_pct); // discount percentage
                }
            }
        });
}, 1000);
```